# How to put the 'Ctrl' key over the 'Win' key in Ubuntu 13.10?

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout

In previous versions of Ubuntu, one could allow the keyboard option to map the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key on the <kbd>⌘ Win</kbd> key. This is very useful for users who constantly have to switch between OS X and Ubuntu. Is there any clean way to do it through the Ubuntu interface?

I have also tried using an .Xmodmap configuration (see [How do I  remap command key to be the control key on a Macbook 4,1?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/42907/how-do-i-remap-command-key-to-be-the-control-key-on-a-macbook-4-1)).

It works when I run manually xmodmap on the file, but I seem to be unable to make it the default option (e.g.: I need to run the script every time I log in).

Any ideas on how to solve this? Has this option vanished forever?

Comment: Why don't you add the script at your Startup Applications?

Comment: As previous comment suggests, [here is the link](http://askubuntu.com/questions/48321/how-do-i-start-applications-automatically-on-login) which will help you to do so.

Answer (score 1):

The gnome-tweak-tool provides an option "Left Alt is swapped with Left Win". You may install gnome-tweak-tool with `sudo apt install gnome-tweak-tool` and the option can be found in the "Typing" menu.

Answer (score 0):

Had the issue too. The problem with the xmodmap is it needs to know what environment to run under. So the solution I used is to put it in a script file and make the script executable:

```
#!/bin/bash
xmodmap /home/jed/.xmodmaprc
```

For more info, see:

- http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1558155
- [How do I  remap command key to be the control key on a Macbook 4,1?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/42907/how-do-i-remap-command-key-to-be-the-control-key-on-a-macbook-4-1)